Can't bring the graph higher on the y-axis
The goal is to get a slowly decreasing function where x is between -0.2 and 0, and y is between 1 and 1.2.
I've plotted this formula in Python:
\begin{align}y=1−(\frac{x+1.5}{a})^n,\text{where a =0.01, n=20}\end{align}
I wanted to get a decreasing function between -0.2 and 0, and have managed to do so
here.
It is my desired curve, however on the y-axis it goes from 0 to around -3. I want this decrease to happen from 1.2 to 1.
I have tried increasing the '1' in the beginning of the formulat, but the graph does not move up or down the y-axis no matter how big or small the number is.
What is the reason why it does not move around the y-axis? Is there a way to get the similar graph but from y = [1.2, 1]?

Careful - the y-axis is scaled by $10^{43}$ so your numbers are large!
